# Saving data from Listener to database in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, events, event-listener

```
    <?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\ProductCreated;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use App\Models\ProductTwo;

class StoreProductIntoDBListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Events\ProductCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ProductCreated $event)
    {
        $data = [
            'barcode' => "barkod-2024",
            'title' => "Fragrance Black Erkek Afrodizyak Parfüm 50 ml",
            'productMainId' => "1042",
            'brandId' => 1417218,
            'categoryId' => 661,
            'quantity' => 100

        ];
        ProductTwo::create($data);
        
        \Log::info('Veritabanı kaydı başarılı!');

    }
}
```

I want to save the data to the database in Listener, but even though I wrote everything correctly, I get a warning saying Table is not defined.
Is there any extra action I need to do while saving the data to the database in the listener?

Comment: What is the table name for `ProductTwo`, and does it exist in the database?

Comment: This is a test table. I have one Product table and I named it this way because it contains real data. The ProductTwo table also exists in the database

Comment: show the actual error message